# XML Path vs more connections

Tags: t-sql, orm, resultset, for-xml-path

I have need of a grid which lists Orders, and associated data.  (Purely fictional example)

For simplicity:

```
OrderID
OrderName
OrderDate
Collection Parts
Collection Destinations
Collection SuppliersInvolved
```

The grid should display each order, but also the textual description from each collection,
eg:

```
OrderID  OrderName OrderDate  Parts  Destinations     SupplierInvolved
   2        davo    21/5/12   A,B,C  London, Paris    SuppA,SuppB,SuppC
```

Now, this grid may have up to two hundred rows.

This issue is, the bespoke ORM we use has some major slowness issues mapping multi-PK results sets into unique objects.

eg.

```
OrderID  OrderName OrderDate  Part  Destination     Supplier
   2        davo    21/5/12   A       London         SuppA
   2        davo    21/5/12   B       London         SuppA
   2        davo    21/5/12   A       London         SuppB
   2        davo    21/5/12   B       London         SuppB
```

It has this issue even with 1 collection involved in the result set.  The query itself executes absolutely fine and fast, it's the mapping which is the issue.

So, I am left with two options really (as far as I can see):

1. Get Orders result set, For each order in resultset, fetch Parts, fetch Destination, fetch Supplier, etc.  This would in turn mean 601 calls to DB.
2. Use **FOR XML PATH** to group each collection together.  Means more CPU intensive and read heavy initial query.

I'm wondering, firstly, which of the above two approaches would seem the better, and, secondly, whether there are other better approaches I haven't thought of.  Issue is that both have to use rubbishy object mapper (can't create my own DAL mapping procedure just for this query's result set).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that mapping will be an issue because you can go ahead with Custom Properties and then map that. However, here is a Fox XML Path solution for the problem.

```
Declare @t Table(OrderId Int,OrderName Varchar(10),OrderDate DateTime,Part Varchar(2),Destination Varchar(10),Supplier Varchar(10))
Insert Into @t Values
(2,'davo','5/21/12','A','London','SuppA'),
(2,'davo','5/21/12','B','London','SuppB'),
(2,'davo','5/21/12','C','Paris','SuppC')

Select 
    OrderId
    ,OrderName
    ,OrderDate
    ,Parts = Stuff( (Select Distinct ',' +Cast(Part As Varchar(max))
                     From @t t2 where t1.OrderId = t2.OrderId
                     For Xml Path('')
                     ),1,1,'')
    ,Destinations = Stuff(  (Select Distinct ',' +Cast(Destination As Varchar(max))
                     From @t t2 where t1.OrderId = t2.OrderId
                     For Xml Path('')
                     ),1,1,'')

    ,SupplierInvolved = Stuff(  (Select Distinct ',' +Cast(Supplier As Varchar(max))
                     From @t t2 where t1.OrderId = t2.OrderId
                     For Xml Path('')
                     ),1,1,'')
From @t t1
Group By t1.OrderId,t1.OrderName,t1.OrderDate
```

The result is

[image]

Coming to option 1, write a store procedure that will get the record set (using joins among the tables like Orders,Parts, Suppliers etc.) and then you can map those again using  custom Properties. Now If you want also do the custom formatting at your presentation layer.

Comment: Hi, do you mean Custom Attributes?  I have the query using For XML Path already.  I've noticed against live data that the query will be averages 3-5 seconds across around two thousand records.  This is too slow for me. How would I map with Custom Attributes?